# Do all class specific resources decay?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do all class specific resources (Fury, etc), slowly decay over time?  If so, do they all decay at the same rate?  So far I've focused on Barbarian, and I'm trying to understand how similar other classes are, since I party with them, and in the long run I'll play as them.

Comment: Most don't (I don't have the game yet to test them all). I think barbarian's is the only one that decays. Most replenish (either quickly or slowly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Only Fury decays over time. Spirit (for Monks) starts at 0, like Fury, but does not decay until used. All other resource pools are full by default and *regenerate* over time.

Comment: And as an addendum, both Barbarians and Monks have optional passives that change their resource to (re)generate instead of decay.